# Save views and fragments in a file

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist, save

My app allows the user to add images and texts to the view. So now I want to save the fragments so that they can make amendments to it later and customise it further. However, I cannot find a way to save the list of fragments. I have tried:

```
ArrayList<FlashcardsTemplateActivity> FlashCards = new ArrayList<FlashcardsTemplateActivity>();
public void Save() {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        oos.writeObject(FlashCards);
        byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.d("Error! Failed!", "Save: Failed");
        Log.d("Error! Failed!", ex.getMessage());
        Log.d("Error! Failed!", ex.toString());

    }
}
```

However, this throws an java.io.NonSerializableException.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not as easy as just writing the array that contains some views to a stream. You will first have to convert those views into any kind of format which you prefer and can be stored in a file. Options would be to convert them to JSON, XML or plain text - you could also create a raw binary of the views. When reading them, you need a parser which parses the objects and recreates the views and adds them to the layout.
When the images contain custom bitmaps, then you will also have to store the bitmaps inside this file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in described way.
You need some intermediate objects to save and read from database or other persistence layer. 
Here is starting point how you can save objects in DB: [Save data in a local database using Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/)